# Faire causative : Pronom indirect et non pas un pronom emphatique ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, constructions-causatives

Ce qui suit est issu de la P164 de *Advanced French Grammar* de V Mazet :

> If both the object and the subject of the infinitive are named in the sentence, the subject is relpaced by the indirect object pronoun, and the object is replaced by the direct object pronoun. There's never aggreement between the past participle and the direct object pronoun.
>
> Je fais réparer ma voiture **par le mécanicien**. = Je la **lui** fais réparer.

1. Pourquoi pas : Je la fais réparer par [ lui  = le mécanicien ] ?
   Voire, pourquoi le pronom indirect et non pas : par + pronom emphatique ?
2. Pourquoi n'existe-t-il pas de concordance entre le participe passé et le pronom d'objet direct ?

---

Supplément daté le 19 déc 2013 :

1. A la lumière de la réponse d'utilisateur un francophone, « Je la fais réparer **par lui** » est également juste. À partir de ceci, comment dérive-t-on & déduit-on « Je la **lui** fais réparer par lui ».
   Comment est-ce que « **par lui** » est devenue et remplacée par «  **lui**  » ?

Comment: Quel participe passé ? Il n'y en a pas dans cette phrase.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, j'ai supposé un _je l'ai fait réparer_.

Comment: @Unfrancophone: Je vous suis reconnaissant. C'est ce que je voulais dire mais avais oublié à écrire.

Answer (score 2):

> Je la fais réparer par lui.

Est aussi possible si on veut insister.

> Pourquoi n'existe-t-il pas de concordance entre le participe passé et le pronom d'objet direct ?

En supposant qu'il s'agit d'une phrase comme *je l'ai fait réparer*.

Parce que le pronom n'est pas l'objet direct de ce verbe mais de celui qui est à l'infinitif.

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant et ai plussoyé. Prière de me faire savoir de ma révision si nécessaire; je pense que `par` devrait être `pas` ? D'ailleurs, j'ai ajouté un supplément à mon OP